# Partial application argument manipulation with Ramda

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

This obviously doesn’t work- as `always` isn’t called with `whenTrueValue` like it does in the top implementation of `whenPropTrueAlways`. Is there a way to manipulate calling another method like I'm trying to do? Substituting a particular value for an argument, as well as applying a function to another argument?

```
export const whenPropEq = curry((key, predicateValue, whenTrueFn, data) =>
  when(
    propEq(key, predicateValue),
    whenTrueFn,
  )(data),
);

const whenPropTrueAlways = curry((key, whenTrueValue, data) =>
  whenPropEq(key, true, always(whenTrueValue), data),
);

// Doesn't work, for obvious reasons- just trying to illustrate the desire
const whenPropTrueAlways = whenPropEq(__, true, always(__), __);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you could write this:

```
const whenPropTrue = useWith(flip(whenPropEq)(true), [identity, always, identity]);
```

[`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) is one of the more unusual Ramda functions (along with its sister function [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge).)  It helps one make points-free things that otherwise might be difficult to do.  But oftentimes I find that when it's difficult to make things points-free, it's a sign that one shouldn't bother to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll admit I haven't gotten familiar with `useWith` or `converge`- I'll dig into them a bit. So in this particular case, are you saying you wouldn't bother trying to make the partial application method point free?

Comment: I don't know.  It's not my call.  I think you need to ask yourself, looking at such a points-free solution and the original pointed one, which one you (or someone else maintaining your code) would understand better when reopening this after a year away from it.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!